Can I post comments on [tips] questions with golfing tips if I don't understand the tip myself?
Disclaimer: I am the author of the posts mentioned here.Disclaimer: Sorry if the title doesn't make a whole lot of sense, I will try to clear up any confusion below.
So recently I posted the tips question "Tips for golfing in Emmental" because I had recently at that time come across Emmental and was curious as to how one could golf in it.
4 days ago, I posted this answer to the "Hello World" challenge in Emmental because I thought that it would be nice to test my ability to program in Emmental, and two days ago, I received a second comment from user @Adeile which utilized duping and utilizing the queue to shave off 7 bytes.
While I have a feeling that utilizing the queue could shave bytes off in some cases, I don't feel like I understand it enough to be able to post an actual tip to show how it could.
So, instead of posting a tip on my question about golfing in Emmental, I am thinking of creating a comment suggesting that utilizing the queue could help with golfing in it. However, I don't really know if this is allowed or not.
My question is, can I post comments on tips questions if I have a tip that I know can shave off bytes in some cases but don't know enough about how it works to actually be able to support it with specific examples?

I don't think the mods are really going to be going around deleting comments for being wrong. You can comment whatever you want and as long as its not abusive or irrelevant it will probably stay around.

There's no problem with doing this...
...but it has its own issues.

As Wheat Wizard said, we mods aren't really gonna go around deleting useful comments such as those with tips under tips questions. So, in theory, you are completely fine to do this.
However, first, comments are disposable. While I don't expect any mod to delete your comment, they aren't meant to stick around, and get can caught up in mass deletions very easily. Unlike answers, which require individual effort to delete each one.
Second, comments have much less quality control than answers. You can upvote and flag them to indicate their value or inappropriateness, but ultimately, they don't have the same upvote/downvote/flag/accept/etc. options available to answers that indicate their quality to more casual viewers of the site.
This isn't even mentioning the fact that comments can get collapsed into each other under a post with lots of them, and other ways that they can be hidden from someone browsing the site.

In short, you are more than welcome to do so, and for very minor tips, you'll find lots of comments that do. But if there's anything of substance, even if it isn't a 100% clean, polished and refined tip, an answer is much more preferable.
